# Put Correct [Order] When inserting multiple ROWS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following query,

```
INSERT INTO ProductsImages (BaseProductId, ImageId, [Order], CreatorId, CreationDateUtc, LastModifierId, LastModificationDateUtc)
SELECT @BaseProductId, Id, ??, @UserId, GETUTCDATE(), @UserID, GETUTCDATE() FROM @ImageIDs;
```

I am inserting multiple records into `ProductsImages` table. But the problem is that I need to insert Order = 1 for the first row, Order = 2 for the second row and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL data doesn't have any inherent order, so you need to define it yourself, which you can do using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
SELECT @BaseProductId, Id, Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY ....),
@UserId, GETUTCDATE(), @UserID, GETUTCDATE() FROM @ImageIDs;
```

You need to specify the ordering you require in the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use the sequence object:

```
create sequence dbo.seq
as int
start with 1
increment by 1;

INSERT INTO ProductsImages (BaseProductId, ImageId, [Order], CreatorId, CreationDateUtc, LastModifierId, LastModificationDateUtc)
SELECT @BaseProductId, Id, next value for dbo.seq, @UserId, GETUTCDATE(), @UserID, GETUTCDATE() FROM @ImageIDs;
```